# save variables: add new values to a new row in each iteration MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save

I have a loop as below

```
for chnum=1:300
   PI=....
   area=....

   save ('Result.mat' ,'chnum' ,'PI' ,'area',' -append') %-append
    %% I like to have sth like below
    % 1, 1.2,3.7
    % 2, 1,8, 7.8
    % .....

end
```

but it doesn't save. Do you have any idea why?

Best

Comment: There's an extra space in the `'-append'` option that shouldn't be there.

Comment: If my answer helped you in solving your problem, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Analysis of the Problem

The [matlab help page for `save`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) states that the `-append` option will append *new variables* to the saved file. It will not append new rows to the already saved matrices.

#### Solution

To achieve what you intended you have to store your data in matrices and save the whole matrice with a single call to `save()`.

```
PI = zeros(300,1);
area = zeros(300,1);
for chnum=1:300
   PI(chnum)=.... ;
   area(chnum)=.... ;
end
save ('Result.mat' ,'chnum' ,'PI' ,'area');
```

For nicer memory management I have added a pre-allocation of the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Well, even if it's not part of the question, I don't think that you are using a good approach to save your calculations. Reading/writing operations performed on the disk (saving data on a file is falls in this case) are very expensive in terms of time. This is why I suggest you to proceed as follows:

```
res = NaN(300,2)

for chnum = 1:300
    PI = ...
    area = ...

    res(chnum,:) = [PI area]; % saving chnum looks a bit like an overkill since you can retrieve it just using size(res,1) when you need it...
end

save('Result.mat','res');
```

Basically, instead of processing a row and saving it into the file, then processing another row and saving it into the file, etc... you just save your whole data into a matrix and you just save your final result to file.